# Creating subplots with a for loop Pandas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plot

I want to create 3 subplots below with the subplot with the coordinates stated in the for loop parameters as `add_plot`. The format of `add_plot` is `nrows, ncols ,cells`. But I get an error when I try to implement it. How can I modify the contents of the for loop within `Graphing()` to achieve this?

Error:

```
ValueError: Single argument to subplot must be a three-digit integer, not (2, 2, 1)
```

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 5, 1, 1, 6], 'col2': [6, 2, 1, 7, 3, 5, 3, 3, 9], 
     'label':['Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old'],
     'date': ['2022-01-24 10:07:02', '2022-01-27 01:55:03', '2022-01-30 19:09:03', '2022-02-02 14:34:06',
              '2022-02-08 12:37:03', '2022-02-10 03:07:02', '2022-02-10 14:02:03', '2022-02-11 00:32:25',
              '2022-02-12 21:42:03']})

def Graphing():
    #Size of the figure 
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))

    #Creating the dataframe 
    df = pd.DataFrame({
                      'date' : datetime, 
                      'col1': data['col1']
    })
    
    for subplot_,add_plot in (zip(
                         ['sub1','sub2','sub3'],
                         [(2,2,1), (2,2,1), (2,1,2)])): 
        subplot_ = fig.add_subplot(add_plot)
        
    # Show Graph 
    plt.show()

Graphing()
```

Comment: I think maybe you should do `fig.add_subplot(*add_plot)` on your for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This still raises a `NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined` as you didn't define `datetime` in your code, but shouldn't raise any error for the subplots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 5, 1, 1, 6], 'col2': [6, 2, 1, 7, 3, 5, 3, 3, 9], 
     'label':['Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old'],
     'date': ['2022-01-24 10:07:02', '2022-01-27 01:55:03', '2022-01-30 19:09:03', '2022-02-02 14:34:06',
              '2022-02-08 12:37:03', '2022-02-10 03:07:02', '2022-02-10 14:02:03', '2022-02-11 00:32:25',
              '2022-02-12 21:42:03']})

def Graphing():
    #Size of the figure 
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))

    #Creating the dataframe 
    df = pd.DataFrame({
                      'date' : datetime, 
                      'col1': data['col1']
    })
    
    for subplot_,add_plot in (zip(
                         ['sub1','sub2','sub3'],
                         [(2,2,1), (2,2,1), (2,1,2)])): 
        subplot_ = fig.add_subplot(*add_plot)
        
    # Show Graph 
    plt.show()

Graphing()
```

Comment: Also, note that the first 2 subplots will overlap

Comment: thank you is there a way to stop the overlapping? I tried `sub1._shared_x_axes.remove(sub2)` and `sub1._shared_y_axes.remove(sub2)` but it does not work

Comment: I applied a portion of the code so `datetime` does not work sorry about that

Comment: The tuple (2, 2, 1) means you are dividing the whole figure in 2 rows and 2 columns, the 1 means you are placing the subplot in the first space (from left to right and top to bottom). So you are placing the first subplots in the same space. do something like `[(2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 1, 2)]` and you'll get a figure with two rows, the first one containing the first 2 subplots (occupying half the width of the figure) and the second will contain 1 subplot (occupying the full width of the figure).